# How to know the cause of thrown exception in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, exception

I'm not that expert in debugging c++ applications using Visual Studio, but in c# usually whenever you have and exception, the application breaks at the exact location in your code that caused the exception.
In c++ using Visual Studio 2017 the debugger breaks so deep like breaking until system.cpp file which is totally not helping me knowing what is line number in my code that caused this exception.
As per the exception below, how do I know what is the line number in my code caused it?
[image]

[Update]

I managed to get what I want from the Call Stack as per the clipping below:
[image]

Comment: Open the call stack window.

Comment: Rusty, is it the line just before [External Code] in the Call Stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Call Stack* to see where in your code the program broke.
To display the call stack window, from the menu:

```
Debug-->Windows-->Call Stack
```

Then double-click on the top line that corresponds to anything in your own code. This is where your own code made the program break. You can also move to any previous function in the call stack, examine the variables, etc.

In release mode, C++ exceptions do not trace the call stack. You need to design and implement your own exception-handling mechanism.

Comment: I see multiple lines, the last one is called [External Code]. Double clicking the line before that is taking me to my code. So this is the line with issue?

Comment: Yes, must be. But that does not mean necessarily that the erroneous code is at this line. It might be the result of a previous error. The call stack gives you the possibility to examine all the stack frames.